# How do I debug server-side errors on MERN?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have this front-end code:

```
export const CreatePage = () => {
const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
const {request} = useHttp()
const [content, setContent] = useState('')
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
const [lead, setLead] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    window.M.updateTextFields()
},[])

const postHandler = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await request('/api/post/generate', 'POST', {title: title, lead: lead, content: content}, {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`
        })
        console.log(data)
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

And this back-end code:

```
router.post('/generate', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const baseURL = config.get('baseURL')
    const {title, lead, content} = req.body

    // if (!title || !lead || !content) {
    //     return res.status(422).json({error: 'Please, input ALL fields'})
    // }

    const Post = new Post({
        title, lead, content, owner: req.body.user.userId // req.user.userId
    })

    await Post.save()
    res.status(201).json({Post})

} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({message: 'Something went wrong'})
}})
```

I've tried a lot of things, but I still get this error. I know this is a server-side error, but that's all I have been able to figure out.

P.S. If there are any questions about the code, I will add it later.

UPD: By the way, could it be a problem's reason? Console log:

```
[1] Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/post/generate from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
```

Comment: It usually means the backend server is off.

Comment: No, I use npm run dev (concorrently). This app with login system. And login system works correctly.

Comment: can you show us the `package.json` file?

Comment: I guess you are interested in that  `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it's because of cors, you just can't send request from different url's. Try to install cors and configure it:

```js
const cors = require("cors");

app.use("/", require('./src/routes'));
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}))
```